# c# cannot convert system.data.entity set

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am getting this error and I am not sure why I have tried to IQueryable or to the convert object but still getting this error.

[image]
Interface

```
 IQueryable<Template> UpdateRegimenCodeId(Regimen Regimens);
```

Controller

```
TemplatesDataService.UpdateRegimenCodeId(template.Regimens);
```

DataService

```
 public Regimen UpdateRegimens(regimens)
        {
            if (regimens != null)
            {
                foreach (var regimen in regimens)
                {

                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `UpdateRegimenCodeId` is expecting a single instance of `Regimen`:

```
IQueryable<Template> UpdateRegimenCodeId(Regimen Regimens);
```

Semantically, and supported by the error message, you are passing it a collection of `Regimen`s:

```
TemplatesDataService.UpdateRegimenCodeId(template.Regimens);
```

To put it another way, the method is expecting an apple and you are passing it a basket of apples.

It's not clear from the code shown what that method is intended to do or what the returned value is intended to represent, but essentially you have a few options:

1. Select the one element from `template.Regimens` that you want to use and pass that one element to the method.
2. Loop over `template.Regimens` and pass each element to the method.
3. Create a version of the method which accepts a collection instead of a single object.

Which approach is appropriate depends on what you're trying to do.  But ultimately the error itself comes down to the difference between a single object (an apple) and a collection of objects (a basket of apples).

Comment: if I change the interface to this IQueryable<Regimen> can I send the collection?

Comment: @Jefferson: That should work.  Personally I'm more a fan of `IEnumerable<>` to keep it as simple as possible.  Unless within the method the argument *needs* to be `IQueryable<>`, of course.  Depends on what the method does.

Comment: will the data service need to change too?

Comment: @Jefferson: If you change the interface then you would need to change anything which implements the interface, that's pretty much a given.